# YUI paginator infinity records in table

Tags: pagination, yui

I am using YUI for displaying data.

This row is used for set count of records per page:

```
rowsPerPageOptions : [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ]
```

Does it have ability to set infinity number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just [ 20, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 'all' ]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using custom page count names and max int.

```
rowsPerPageOptions       : [  
                                    { value : 20, text : '20' },  
                                    { value : 50, text : '50' },  
                                    { value : 100, text : '100' },
                                    { value : 250, text : '250' },
                                    { value : 500, text : '500' },
                                    { value : 1000, text : '1000' },
                                    { value : 9007199254740992, text : 'All' }],
```